# <class 'float'> versus 'float' in Python type annotations

Tags: python, python-typing

When I try to compare the type annotations of an abstract base class and an implementation, I sometimes get two different type annotations with `inspect.getfullargspec()`.

Here is the abstract base class and below a stub of the implementation:

```py
import abc
from typing import List, Tuple


class Abstract(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_hscodes(self, *, confidence_threshold: float = 0.0, **kwargs):
        pass


class Concrete(Abstract):
    def get_hscodes(self, *, confidence_threshold: float = 0.0, **kwargs):
        likely = self.get_likely_hscodes(confidence_threshold=confidence_threshold, **kwargs)
        return [i[0] if i else (None, 0.0) for i in likely]

    def get_likely_hscodes(
        self, *, confidence_threshold: float = 0.0, **kwargs
    ) -> List[List[Tuple]]:
        pass
```

Now if I run:

```py
import inspect

print(inspect.getfullargspec(Abstract.get_hscodes))
print(inspect.getfullargspec(Concrete.get_hscodes))
```

I'm getting differing results:

```
FullArgSpec(args=['self'], varargs=None, varkw='kwargs', defaults=None, kwonlyargs=['confidence_threshold'], kwonlydefaults={'confidence_threshold': 0.0}, annotations={'confidence_threshold': <class 'float'>})
FullArgSpec(args=['self'], varargs=None, varkw='kwargs', defaults=None, kwonlyargs=['confidence_threshold'], kwonlydefaults={'confidence_threshold': 0.0}, annotations={'confidence_threshold': 'float'})
```

I tried Python 3.8.13 on both Windows and Linux.

Why am I sometimes getting `<class 'float'>` and sometimes just `float`? I have difficulties to even reproduce the problem and don't know where to look for the reason.

Comment: Could it be that, in the file you're implementing `Concrete` you're having a `from __future__ import annotations` line? The difference between `class 'float'>`  and just  `"float"` is that the first is the actual 'float' class and the second one just the string "float" - I can only see a `__future__` import as a possible explanation on why these differ.

Comment: @RobinGugel that was it! There is a `from __future__ import annotations` in only the implementation file! If you can make your comment an answer, I can mark it as solution, if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `from __future__ import annotations` statement in your implementation file this result can be expected.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I have it in only one of the files.
https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/ gives the necessary information how to deal with it. One can use typing.get_type_hints() to compare the annotations also then.